# Unexpected behaviour of c++ string::compare() fn

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The string::compare() has one of its overloaded forms as

```
int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str) const;
```

Now consider following 2 scenarios:

Scenario 1:

```
string s1="steven", s2="steve";
cout<<s1.compare(0, 5,s2);
```

Scenario 2:

```
string s1="steven", s2="stevec";
cout<<s1.compare(0, 5,s2);
```

The O/P in first case is 0(expected) but in 2nd case yields -1(unexpected). The fn call translates to **compare first 5 chars of s1 to those of s2**.So, how come the output is getting affected by 6th char of s2.Can someone please care to explain the reason behind such implementation of a standard library fn.

Answer (score 5):

As described [in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare):

> 2. Compares a [pos1, pos1+count1) substring of this string to str. If `count1 > size() - pos1` the substring is [pos1, size()).

Nothing is said about the second string size. It means that the whole string2 is compared. So everything's as expected.